# Pattern which allow ? . ! , and should contan {0}

Tags: regex

Currently I am wondering about how to work with regular expressions. I have tried many combinations but nothing helped.

I would like to create a pattern which allows only `? . ! ,` and should contain `{0}`

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Can you give examples of strings that should and should not match?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Lorehead..

Comment: Matches
[Your OTP is {0} !.]

Should Not match
[Your OTP is {0} %$^% ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

> [\?|!|\.|,]*\{0}[\?|!|\.|,]*

Comment: Not if he means a literal dot.

Comment: Fixed that, Stack Overflow scrapped the '\' because I didn't escape it. Thanks!

Comment: Thats worked bro.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the exact pattern for my problem.

```
(?=.*\{0\}).*
```